# same Push Notification for Multiple apps of different bundle id

Tags: apple-push-notifications, cfbundleidentifier

Application "A"(com.xxx.bundleid)is already in app store ,now im working on Application "B" , i have  old csr as well as p12 file i.e is used for application "A".

Now i use different bundle id for my app "B" . Even i use same csr file from "A",  the produced The SSL certificate aps_developer_identity.cer will be different (for different bundle id "B")..respectively ck.pem will be different.

i.e for the backend i have to give same ck.pem file that will work for both Apps A & B.

is der any suggetion how to use same  Push Notification for different apps.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

according the apple document, it's no way to use same Push_Notification for different apps.